# NameError at /events path - Undefined Local Variable or Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm quite new to rails and I'm using grape to build an API rails app.

I've been getting this error message after I click on the 'Create Event' button :-

```
NameError at /events

undefined local variable or method `event_params' for #<EventsController:0x00000008f76400>
```

The error points to the controller file for events,

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!
   before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
   @events = Event.all
    if user_signed_in?
     if current_user.is_admin?
       @events = Event.all

       respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.json { render json: @events }
       end

     else
      @events = current_user.events
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @events }
      end
     end
   else
    render json: {}, status: :unauthorized
   end
 end

 def new
  @event = Event.new
 end

 def edit
 end

 def create
  @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)
  respond_to do |format|

     if @event.save
       format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }

       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }

     else
       format.html { render :show, notice: 'You are not allowed to view this.' }
       format.json { render json: {}, status: :unauthorized}
      end
    end
  end
```

And here's the event_params method,

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :event_description, :event_date, :event_time)
end
```

The log file shows,

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-10 14:38:16 +0800
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yRVn4uuxpMVejs/gsG004PIi2JRaWnovGBm7TweGgkf2XpTLzjOZNGanCRVVKSPAV6JzNRWmDzRRbq/dC2KOKQ==", "event"=>{"event_name"=>"ddwq", "event_description"=>"rqreqreqr", "event_date(1i)"=>"2015", "event_date(2i)"=>"8", "event_date(3i)"=>"10", "event_time(1i)"=>"2015", "event_time(2i)"=>"8", "event_time(3i)"=>"10", "event_time(4i)"=>"06", "event_time(5i)"=>"38"}, "commit"=>"Create Event"}
[1m[36mUser Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 34ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method `event_params' for #<EventsController:0x000000082a6540>:
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:37:in `create'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
...
...
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Started POST "/__better_errors/beb9cf3b65f0e36a/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-10 14:38:16 +0800
```

Comment: You forgot to add one more  'end' i.e for your create method.

Comment: My bad, let me edit that part.

Answer (score 0):

Try build instead of new 
replace

`@event = current_user.events.new(event_params)`

by

`@event = current_u`ser.events.build(event_params)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)
  respond_to do |format|

     if @event.save
       format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }

       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }

     else
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render :show, notice: 'You are not allowed to view this.' }
       format.json { render json: {}, status: :unauthorized}
   end
 end ##You have missed the end here
```

And here's the event_params method,

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :event_description, :event_date, :event_time)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that, `event_params` method is not available for the `EventsController`. I think you mistakenly put the `event_params` inside another method or missed an `end` to end the `create` method. It should be an instance method of your `EventsController` class.

This code should work as it is:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @events = Event.all
    if user_signed_in?
      if current_user.is_admin?
        @events = Event.all

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render json: @events }
        end

      else
        @events = current_user.events
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render json: @events }
        end
      end
    else
      render json: {}, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @event = current_user.events.new(event_params)
    respond_to do |format|

      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }

        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }

      else
        format.html { render :show, notice: 'You are not allowed to view this.' }
        format.json { render json: {}, status: :unauthorized}
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:event_name, :event_description, :event_date, :event_time)
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks more like this, 

`class EventsController < ApplicationController'
 'before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :authenticate_user_from_token!
   before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the full code of your EventsController there?

Comment: I have already told  'end' was missing that's why rails could not find event_params method in events controller.

Comment: Actually, she has 2 missing `end`s. One to end the `create` method and another to end the `EventsController` class.

Comment: @ChandimaWijendra According to your latest input, you had 2 missing `ends`. One to end the `create` method and another to end the `EventsController` class. However, I fixed those and updated my answer. Just copy my answer and paste it in your `EventsController` class's code. It should work!

Comment: I'm so sorry. the line `respond_to do |format|` below `else` for `def create` is not supposed to be there. I'll edit the code again.

Comment: @ChandimaWijendra Okay, I have updated my answer again. Just copy and paste it to your `EventsController` class and it should work.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Thank you! I've tried but still the same error. According to the Instance Variables the `@_routes` shows `nil`

Comment: still the same error? Could you paste the log of your application when you try to create an event (with the latest code that I put in my answer)?

Comment: @KMRakibulIslami I have pasted the code in the post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86583/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-chandima-wijendra).

Answer (score 0):

So, the error was a missing 'end' for show method which I didn't post that part.

I completely missed that part because the error was misleading and I assume that it has something to do with the event parameters since the error points there.